# Apache to ignore server url /foo/ and load the page node /foo via Drupals url alias

Tags: apache, drupal

I have a server running **CentOS** on it there is a website that had the folder `/foo/` on root.

```
www.website.com/foo/
```

I also have a **Drupal** page called `foo` which loads on the url

```
www.website.com/foo
```

I understand I could rename the folder etc.. but I am looking for a solution that will allow me to ignore the folder and load the page.

When I try to load the url address it defaults to access the folder instead of using drupals url alias to load the page.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the following line in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```